# Meteor error on email sending

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, meteor

I don't understand why meteor fails on sending email only in production.
In development mode, mail are send without any issue, and in production it fails when the app is run with node.

Here are my versions:

Package:

- email@1.0.12

In development:

- Meteor 1.3.2.4

In production:

- node v4.4.5

> Sending email: to: to@email.test, from: 'source@email.test', subject:
>   My subject, text: basic email content
>
> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'reconnectCount' of
>   false
>       at SMTPClient._actionAUTHComplete (/var/www/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/email/node_modules/simplesmtp/lib/client.js:823:34)
>       at SMTPClient._onData (/var/www/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/email/node_modules/simplesmtp/lib/client.js:329:29)
>       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
>       at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
>       at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:531:20)

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Looks like `mail` package issue. In development mode meteor uses Node JS v0.10.43. Try to change production node JS version.

Comment: Thank you. 
By the way, i'm using some tools like eslint and sass-lint in a CI pipeline which requires more up-to-date version of node...

I've searched some data, and found this article: https://meteorhacks.com/how-meteor-uses-node.html

I'll try to use the node binary provided by meteor to solve this issue, and post if it's ok

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The solution was the one suggested by @Tdm: using the node version provided by meteor.

But, it was a bit tricky to integrate with CI (eslint, sass-lint) who require a recent version of node, so here's how I proceed:

- For my CI lint tests, I use a recent version (v4.4). Set in gitlab CI
- For my production environment, I build another docker machine, based on node v0.10.46 (even if current Meteor is based on v0.10.45).

Thank you Tdm for pointing the issue !